# Invalid transaction when using PAYPAL API

Tags: php, paypal

I am using PAYPAL API.

I success calling the setExpressCheckout (after calling this method I got ACK=Success) and therefore get a full link that I can proceed with.

After getting the full link (https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_flow&SESSION=[SESSION_TOKEN]), the full link represent a page, that includes error.

## The error:

This transaction is invalid. Please return to the recipient's website to complete your transaction using their regular checkout flow.

Return to merchant

At this time, we are unable to process your request. Please return to and try another option

## Here is my Code:

```
<?php

/*.
    require_module 'standard';
    require_module 'standard_reflection';
    require_module 'spl';
    require_module 'mysqli';
    require_module 'hash';
    require_module 'session';
    require_module 'streams';
.*/

//turn php errors on
//ini_set('track_errors', true);
    require_once __DIR__ . "/stdlib/all.php";
    require_once __DIR__ . "/SqlManager.php";

/*. array .*/ $body_data = null;
$body_data_txt = "";
/*. string .*/ $htmlpage  = "";
/*. array .*/ $keyAr  = array();
/*. array .*/ $tokenAr = array();
$response = "";
    /*. SqlManager .*/ $sqlm = null;

session_start();

$url = trim('https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp');
$urlRun = trim('https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');

$body_data = array( 'USER' => *****",
                    'PWD' => "******",                                    
                    'SIGNATURE' => "*****",
                    'VERSION' => "95.0",
                    'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION' => "Sale",
                    'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT' => (string)$_SESSION["AMOUNT"],
                    'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE' => 'USD',
                    'RETURNURL' => "******",
                    'CANCELURL' => "******",
                    'METHOD' => "SetExpressCheckout"
                                );

$body_data_txt = http_build_query($body_data, '', chr(38));
try
{
    $sqlm = new SqlManager(true);
    //create request and add headers
    $params = array(
            'http' => array(
                'protocol_version' => "1.1",
                'method' => "POST",
                'header' => "".
                    "Connection: close\r\n".
                    "Content-Length: ".strlen($body_data_txt)."\r\n".
                    "Content-type: "."application/x-www-form-urlencoded"."\r\n",
                'content' => $body_data_txt
            ));

    //create stream context
     $ctx = stream_context_create($params);

    //open the stream and send request
    try {
        $fp = fopen($url, 'r', false, $ctx);
    } catch(ErrorException $e) {
        throw new ErrorException("cannot open url" . $url . " error:" . $e->getMessage());
    }
     //get response
     $response = (string)stream_get_contents($fp);
     //check to see if stream is open
     if ($response === "") {
        throw new Exception("php error message = " . "$php_errormsg");
     }

     //close the stream
     fclose($fp);   

     $key = explode("&", $response);

     $keyAr = array();
     foreach ($key as $i => $value) {
        $tmpAr = explode("=", $value);
        if(sizeof($tmpAr) > 1) {
            $keyAr[$tmpAr[0]] = $tmpAr[1];
        }
     }

     if (substr($response, 0, 1) === "<") {
        echo $response;
     } else {
            // Extract the response details.
         if((0 == sizeof($keyAr)) || !array_key_exists('ACK', $keyAr) || (string)$keyAr["ACK"] !== "Success") {
            if (array_key_exists('L_ERRORCODE0', $keyAr) && array_key_exists('L_LONGMESSAGE0', $keyAr)) {
               echo cast("string", htmlspecialchars(urldecode((string)$keyAr["L_ERRORCODE0"]))) . ',' .
                    cast("string", htmlspecialchars(urldecode((string)$keyAr["L_LONGMESSAGE0"])));
            } else {
                echo "Unkown server response!";
            }
         } else {
// ********************************************
               $htmlpage = $urlRun . "?cmd=_express-checkout&".  "TOKEN=" . (string)$keyAr["TOKEN"]; // ******************* IS THIS LINE OK????
// ********************************************
               echo "ok," . $htmlpage; 
            } 
        }
    }

catch(Exception $e)
{
  echo 'Message: ||' .cast("string", str_replace('"', '\\"', $e->getMessage())).'||';
}
?>
```

the $htmlpage got the full link (see the line with the asterisks remark 'IS THIS LINE OK')

My account is business account.
What may be the cause for the problem?
Seem kind of configuration problem - are there any setups I shall check?

Thanks :)

Comment: you'll need to provide more information. Please post your complete SetEC API call and response, leaving out your credentials.

Comment: I have just added the code at this post - you can watch it, please.

Comment: Thank you but what I want to see is the result of the code. I want to see the data that is sent to PayPal. The SetEC call, and then the response from paypal.

Comment: The response from paypal is ACK=SUCCESS (may be other codes), but I have realized that I open the paypal page with TOKEN=, and not token= (letter should not be capitalized - That was the problem). I put this as response, and this close the issue. (There had been passed several days, since I encountered the problem). Thanks, anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I have opened the paypal page with 'TOKEN=', and I should open by 'token=' 
(capitalized letter matter).

The line:

$htmlpage = $urlRun . "?cmd=_express-checkout&".  "TOKEN=" . (string)$keyAr["TOKEN"];

should be:

$htmlpage = $urlRun . "?cmd=_express-checkout&".  "token=" . (string)$keyAr["TOKEN"];

Thanks, anyway :)